# How to optimize proc SQL's group by with respect to required size of "work"?

Tags: sql, performance, group-by, sas, diskspace

Complying with Joe's suggestion, here is working sample code:

```
data test;
format id 5. group1 1. group2 1. group3 1. data $1. valid_from ddmmyy10. valid_till ddmmyy10.;
input id  group1  group2  group3  data $ valid_from yymmdd8.  valid_till yymmdd8.;
datalines;
10001 1 0 0 A 2013010120131231
10001 0 1 1 B 2013010120130701
10001 0 1 1 C 2013070120131231
10002 1 1 0 D 2013010120131231
10002 0 1 1 E 2013010120130101
;run;
```

For every group, I need a Flag, indicating whether the minimal value of "valid from" equals the maximal value of "valid till" of those entries sharing an ID which belong to the group. Example given: The ID 10002 has only one valid entry in Group 3, namely the 5th. Therefore the minimal "valid_from" of all valid entries of ID 10002 in group3 (just one entry here, could be more) equals the maximal "valid_till", hence I want a flag. Here is the code that works on the small data set but not on a large one (disk space insufficient).

```
proc sql; create table test2 as select id, group1, group2, group3, data, valid_from, valid_till, 
case when min(valid_from+100000000*(1-group1))=max(valid_till-100000000*(1-group1)) then 1 else 0 end as flag_1 format 1.,
case when min(valid_from+100000000*(1-group2))=max(valid_till-100000000*(1-group2)) then 1 else 0 end as flag_2 format 1.,
case when min(valid_from+100000000*(1-group3))=max(valid_till-100000000*(1-group3)) then 1 else 0 end as flag_3 format 1.
from test group by id;quit;
```

The question is: How much free disk space does this require on the work library? (ideally as a multiple of the size of the dataset, as the real dataset is much bigger). Does the multiple depend on the number of groups? (I don't see why it should but it was suggested)

Bonus question: How can runtime/disc usage be improved? (One way of improving disk usage is storing only group, id and date variables (not the relevant data itself) in a separate dataset and merge the flags back to the original.)

Comment: Why do you need so many flags? Seems to be an inefficient process. You're essentially merging the data back with itself about 10 times so yeah that would need lots of space.

Comment: @ reese so if i have  select *, max(a), max(b), max( c) from any table it would merge the data back with itself 3 times? that would be hugely inefficient indeed, but is it really what happens? it would seem to me that this could and should be done with just one merging back...

Comment: I'm going to vote to close this, and suggest others do to, until you reshape the question.  As it stands now, you're not really asking a single answerable question; you're too far into generalities.  I suggest you delete all of the text above, and rephrase the question as: "I have data that looks like this [sample data, 10-20 lines that shows your data].  I need to do this process to it [explain in english, plus include code for how it works now].  How can I do that on 10GB of data without wiping out my poor hard drive?"

Comment: That would be an answerable question, but as it stands now it's a jumbled mess and despite the wall of text doesn't contain the entire information needed to answer the question.  (And just to be clear, i'm not suggesting deleting this question: just edit it into a better question.)

Comment: @ Joe I see your point, will rephrase the question tomorrow with a working example code

Comment: @ Joe: You claim the questions lacks information: What is missing to answer the question on the very first line?

Answer (score 1):

Your space is used by SORT operation needed because of GROUP BY + even more space for self-merging the original data with summary results.

I'd do:

```
PROC SUMMARY data=LIB.A min max nway;
class ID;
var Var1 Var2 ... Var10;
output out=WORK.MIN_MAX (drop=_freq_ _type_ )
      min(Var1)=minVar1
      max(Var1)=maxVar1....;
RUN;

data =WORK.MIN_MAX;
   set =WORK.MIN_MAX;
   flag_1 = minVar1 = maxVar1;
   ....
   flag_10 = minVar10 = maxVar10;
run;


proc sql;/* or SORT data */
create index ID on LIB.A;
create index ID on WORK.MIN_MAX;
quit;

data LIB.B;
   merge lib.A WORK.MIN_MAX;
   by ID;
run;
```

Comment: As I mentioned, my current workaround is along those lines. I store the variables I need in a different Dataset and merge it back with the original.

Comment: IMHO, that's not a workaround, that's how you should do it - not push it into a single, inefficient step.

Comment: For sorts I had found this (http://www.ciser.cornell.edu/FAQ/SAS/Sort_Large.shtml) so as source and target are on a different disk I would have expected the need of about twice the size of the dataset in the work directory as mentioned on the site, not four times.

Comment: @ Vasja: The question is exactly about *why* and *by how much* the natural way to code (a simple select evrything, group by id) is way more inefficient with respect to disk usage than the solution that is cumbersome to code.

Comment: Sort needs a lot more than double the space.  Three times is the usual recommended assumption for space requirement (this is in SAS documentation on the SORTSIZE option).  Then add on the extra work you're doing, 4x sounds reasonable to me.

Comment: @user1965813, you need to forget about  ideas like the natural way to code when accessing database. You need to understand how the database engine processes code not what is easiest for the dev. Most performant code in databases is far more complicated than what most devs would like to see. However, in databases especially of theh size you are talking about, performance is FAR more important than maintainibility and you will need to understand how to write performant code as your first choice. After a while, this type of code will seem natural and easy.

Answer (score 0):

What error message do you get?  Can you post it?  There are many different types of resources in SAS that you may have exhausted.

Is your compression turned on?

```
options compress=yes;
```

How much free space in the affected SAS libraries do you have before you run your query?  Can you free up large amounts of space?

I am not sure if a Proc Summary will be any more efficient than your proc sql.  They both are doing the same thing but give it a go.  You need a solution that works.  It doesn't have to be pretty.

If that all fails then try splitting your query up either vertically or horizontally.

Comment: It is the disk space that I run out of (as I could see by refreshing the "computer" window, where the available space decreases from the mentioned 40GB to 0). Afterwards it is the "Out of resources" dialogue with the option to cancel submitted statements or quit SAS.